# Painting only one line in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have several lines in an array. When I want to paint just one a certain color, they are all painted that color instead.
What can I can do to make it paint only the lines that I want?

[image: Image Example]

```
var materialSide = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: "#000000"} );
line[i] = new THREE.Line( Geometria[i], materialSide);
.
.
.
line[24].material.color=new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ); 
line[24].material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same material for all the lines; that is why you are seeing that effect. Create another material `materialPainted` that has the different color that you want and then you assign the `materialPainted` material to your line.

```
line[24].material = materialPainted;
```